# CreateDCFromHandle select object TOP coordinate in Python

Tags: python, winapi, coordinates, screenshot, bitblt

I need to capture a specific application window on Windows, even if it is not focused or in the foreground, WITHOUT the window's top header bar, which height I specify manually in 'application_window_topbar_size' variable to keep it simple.

```py
monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0))) # get screen information
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
screen_width = work_area[2] # if taskbar is on the left
screen_height = work_area[3] # if taskbar is on the left

target_window_hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, ("Math Analysis - Google Chrome"))
application_window_topbar_size = 200 # just roughly for testing

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(target_window_hwnd) 
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)    
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, screen_width, screen_height)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

#    saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (screen_width, screen_height), mfcDC, (0, application_window_topbar_size),win32con.SRCCOPY)
    
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(target_window_hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 3)
    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    screen_image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(target_window_hwnd, hwndDC)
```

The capture routine should works for windows handle "WM_PRINT" (thanks for the comment of IInspectable), BUT **I am unable to figure it out how to set the TOP coordinate of the capture area**. In other words, **I would like to capture the target window without the top bar**. Changing the height is one thing, as logically, if the capture rectangle coordinates start at 0,0 then it cuts only the bottom area of the window, not the top. I tried to use `BitBlt()` but I failed.

----------------- Alternative version below based on IInspectable comment

```
target_window_hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, ("Math Analysis - Google Chrome"))
application_window_topbar_size = 200 # just roughly for testing

    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(target_window_hwnd) 
    mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)    
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()

    l, t, r, b = win32gui.GetClientRect(target_window_hwnd)
    screen_width = r - l
    screen_height = b -t

    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, screen_width, screen_height)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)   
    result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(target_window_hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 3)
    bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    screen_image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(target_window_hwnd, hwndDC)
```

Still, altering top coordinate only effect height, not captured content (to be able to capture only the 'document area' of the window, excluding the address bar/toolbar).

Comment: [GetClientRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect) gets you the coordinates of the client area. *"The capture routine works perfectly"* - For some definition of *"perfect"*, I guess. You'll see what that means once you run across a window that doesn't handle the `WM_PRINT` message, or handles it differently from what you expect. Use the [DWM Thumbnail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/thumbnail-ovw) API instead.

Comment: @IInspectable : I edited my original post and rephrased the word "perfect" based on your comment to avoid any mislead, which wasn't my intention.

My target platform is Python (updated header too), and **I could not found a DWM thumbnail example in this context.** May I ask if you could help to guide to one please ? 

Regarding to GetClientRect(), I (wrongly) thought, it requires the window to be in foreground I had added a new code variant using GetClientRect() in my original post, but I am still struggling to set the top coordinate in a way, to get rid of the toolbar area of the window.

Comment: [PrintWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) doesn't allow you to specify the region. It's either full window, or client area. Presumably, you're already requesting to render the client area only. The issue is that it's common for applications to render the entire window (client and non-client, i.e. border, caption, etc.). This is done by creating a window that doesn't have a non-client area at all. In this situation the system no longer has any way to determine the 'logical' client area.

Comment: @IInspectable : sorry, but I am totally confused now. I mean: 1) what about the DWM Thumbnail question if I may I ask?  2) How PrintWindow comes to the equation? Because my target is not to "officially" catch the client/document area, I simply target to have screenshot where I set capture rectangle with coordinates relative to screen coordinates using wiun32 as above to ensure the window doesnt has to be in focus nor set as foreground. Apologize if my missing the point here, but thats why I ask.

Comment: The DWM Thumbnail API is exposed as a collection of [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) objects. I'm sure there are Python bindings that allow you to access COM objects. `PrintWindow` is the system API you are calling, and my previous comment explains how it behaves in situations where implementers of a window class choose to not use the system-provided non-client area implementation. Since you are passing a value of `3` for the `nFlags` argument that part is relevant.

Comment: @IInspectable : Thank you for your reply again. May I ask if you could help with either a concrete python code example for the DWM solution or a correction on the code above? As I did not found anything concrete during my searches, why I ended to ask for help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search and trials, I realized that the most obvious solution is to CROP the screenshot after it made. This way, the unwanted part (in my case the top bar) can be easily get rid off.

Cropping is easy with PIL Image:

```
box = (left, top, right, bottom)
screen_image.crop(box)
```